# How to force EclipseLink to create column for subclass in InheritanceType.JOINED strategy?

Tags: inheritance, jpa, eclipselink

I have two classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="a_table")
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="jdoclass", length=255)
public abstract class A {
  @Id
  @Column(name="id")
  private int id;

  @Column(name="other_id")
  private int otherID;

  public A(){
  }
  ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="b_table", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"other_id", "different_id"}))
public class B extends A {
  @Column(name="other_id")
  private int otherID;

  @Column(name="different_id")
  private int differentID;

  public B() {
  }
  ...
}
```

When EclipseLink creates SQL, it omits otherID field from class B and doesn't create column in DB for that field. Even if I change column name in class B, column still is not created.

It is pretty understandable - the same field exists in parent class.
But for some reasons I really need this column to be created (one of them is I need to put it in UniqueConstraint table).

I found one solution: change "otherID" field name in class B. Then column is created properly. But I would like to avoid changing name of this field and I threat this solution as the final one.

Are there other solutions to force this column to be created?

Comment: I would definitely use another field name, because this one hides the field from the superclass. How would you do to create a JPQL query that searches for `A.otherID` or `B.otherID`?

Comment: Lets say I don't want to search for otherID. Besides, it worked for OpenJPA. Now I want it to work in EclipseLink :)

Comment: If you don't want to search for it, the field is completely invisible outside of the class. So its name shouldn't matter. It's just a private field. Why do you care?

Comment: I'm responsible for transition of large project which has been working with OpenJPA and should work with EclipseLink in future. Providen code is just sample - there is a lot of classes and subclasses with such situation so I would like to aviod changing name of fields. Second thing is that if I change field name, name of setter and getter should be changed too (to fulfill JavaBean standards). But it cannot be done, because setter and getter for this field must override setter and getter from parent.

Comment: The JavaBeans standard doesn't say anything about the name of your private fields. To the contrary. JavaBeans promote encapsulation of private fields. They can have a name different from the one used by the accessor methods. There can even be no field at all.

Comment: I finally changed names of all these fields :) Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `InheritanceType.JOINED` make sure `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` with the database.
Make sure the table and columen of `entity` with `database`.
Try as below;

Person.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="PERSON")
    @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
    @DiscriminatorColumn(name = "Person_Type")
    public abstract class Person {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "ID")
        private int id;
        @Column(name = "NAME")
        private String name;

        public Person() {
        }

        //getter and setter
    }
```

Student.java

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "STUDENT")
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    public class Student extends Person {
        @Column(name = "ROLE_NO")
        private String rollNo;
        @Column(name = "COURSE")
        private String course;

        public Student() {
        }

        public Student(String name, String rollNo, String course) {
            super(name);
            this.rollNo = rollNo;
            this.course = course;

        }
        // getter and setter
    }
```